# Playing audio files in WPF

Tags: wpf, audio

I am trying to play audio files in WPF and I am currently using the following code:

```
    FileTextBox.Text = selectedFileName;
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.Open(new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Relative ));
    mp.Play();
```

It's working well, except that it doesn't plays the sound. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Stu is correct the mp object is disposed after leaving scope.  Declare mp outside the method.

Answer (score 6):

Your MediaPlayer object is probably being garbage collected before it has a chance to play the file because it has local scope. Try making the media player object a member variable of a class that has application lifetime and see if this fixes it.